# R: Conditional filtering out date range

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data:

```
date_time            flag
2016-04-02 08:56:06  0
2016-04-02 14:50:24  0
2016-04-02 14:56:27  0
2016-04-02 14:56:27  1
2016-04-02 18:56:29  0
2016-04-02 18:56:44  1
2016-04-02 18:56:45  1
2016-04-02 19:05:52  1
```

The logic is this, for everytime `flag` is set as `1`, I'd look at the datetime, and for any entry within 5 minutes prior and with `flag == 0` will be removed. Anything else will remain intact. So the following is what I'd expect:

```
date_time            flag
2016-04-02 08:56:06  0
2016-04-02 14:50:24  0
2016-04-02 14:56:27  1
2016-04-02 18:56:44  1
2016-04-02 18:56:45  1
2016-04-02 19:05:52  1
```

Is there anyway to do that in R?

Note: To import the data in R

```
structure(list(
     date_time = structure(c(1459612566, 1459633824, 1459634187, 1459634187, 1459648589, 1459648604, 1459648605, 1459649152), 
     class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
     flag = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
     .Names = c("date_time", "flag"), 
     row.names = c(NA, -8L),
     class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey @bouncyball, I've added the code in, almost forgot about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way, using the **`lubridate`** package, the `apply` function, and a function we define:

```
library(lubridate)
#generate the data
dat <- structure(list(date_time = c("2016-04-02 08:56:06", "2016-04-02 14:50:24", 
                                    "2016-04-02 14:56:27", "2016-04-02 14:56:27", 
                                    "2016-04-02 18:56:29", "2016-04-02 18:56:44", 
                                    "2016-04-02 18:56:45", "2016-04-02 19:05:52"), 
flag = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("date_time", "flag"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
#create subsets
dat_0 <- subset(dat, flag == 0)
dat_1 <- subset(dat, flag == 1)

#define function to perform calculation
calc_diff <- function(time1, time2, upper = 0, lower = -5, units = 'mins'){
  dtime <- as.numeric(difftime(time1, time2, units = units)) # calculate difference
  dtime >= lower & dtime <= upper #compute logical
}

#apply over the rows of dat_0, checking for any times
#within 5 and 0 minutes prior
find_rows <- apply(dat_0, 1, 
                   function(d) any(calc_diff(ymd_hms(d[1]), ymd_hms(dat_1$date_time))))
 #bind applicable rows to dat_1
rbind(dat_0[!find_rows,], dat_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a test data like:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(date_time = Sys.time() + minutes(round(runif(1000, max = 10000))),
                 flag = rbinom(1000, size = 1,  prob = .1))
dt <- dt[order(date_time)]
```

With this test data, what you need is created through this code. For each of the observations with flag == 1, `lapply` the function where you can find less than 300 seconds difference AND flag == 0. This will give the list of rows to be erased. The code then `unlist` and find the unique row numbers to be removed. The last line remove the observations.

```
remove <- lapply(dt[, which(flag == 1)], 
       function(x) {
         which(dt[, date_time - dt[x, date_time]]) > -300 &
               dt[, date_time - dt[x, date_time]]) < 0 &
                 dt[, flag] == 0)}) %>% unlist %>% unique
dt_sub <- dt[-remove]
```